# Burninate [image]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have both [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) and [image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) which seems absolutely silly to me.

The images tag has 240 questions, a wiki tag, and 11 followers. The image tag on the other hand has 8 questions, no wiki, and 0 followers.

Can we please burn the image tag?

Comment: Trogdor strikes again. Good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch, I've performed a merge and added a synonym.

Comment: I miss it already.. :(