# Is there any use to the [images] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

With the [recent burnination of](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/burninate-image) [image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image), I start wondering what the use of [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) actually is. The tag excerpt mentions that it should contain questions relating to the design of images. Arguably, that 99% of the questions of this site.

Is there a good use for [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)? If not, can we, well, burninate it?

Answer (score 4):

I find it useful when combined with other tags. Sometimes I can almost spell out the title with the tags.

An example of the top of my head..

Say we have someone asking how to resize a batch of images for their website design. I would usually tag it with:

[website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) [resize](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resize) [batch-processing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing) [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) [software-being-used](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-being-used)

Leaving out the images tag here *would* make the information or *the context created by the tags* not as complete as before. Like so:

[website-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) [resize](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resize) [batch-processing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing) [software-being-used](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-being-used)

Additionally, if we burninated the [images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) tag we would no longer have an explicit categorisation on our site stating that we accept questions about images. We'd still know, but it wouldn't be explicitly stated for the search engines.

Comment: I agree, used in combination it can be a good tag. It's not the fanciest, but it has its uses.

Comment: Okay, it's morning so cut me some slack. But I saw that [tag:software-being-used] tag and my eyes widened thinking "_what the—why is that a tag?!_"

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Dom.   (see it happens)

The [image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) is similar to [resolution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resolution) or [color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) or any of a dozen others.

It's not a great tag in itself, but it does narrow a question down into a specific sub-category which can be helpful.